# Pyside to build PyQT designer 4 UI file always results in error

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, pyside

Using Pyside-uic -o pythonfilename.py uifilename.ui to convert my PyQT4 designer GUI to python code.   Seems to build just fine with no errors, but when I run the file, it consistently crashes, with type errors I can't solve.

First error gave me trouble because I set a "max size".  When I removed the max size, the error changed to be a problem with the palette.   I removed the palette settings, and replaced it with style sheets, and now it's giving me the error:

"TypeError: QWidget.setFont(QFont): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide.QtGui.QFont'"

I doubt there are this many problems with using Pyside to build PyQT UI files(because it seems to be a pretty standard way of doing it), so that leaves me to believe it's something i'm doing.

**Just a note with a bit more info.

This is software we've been using for some time, and the existing UI was built using this exact method.   I inherited the file, and was asked to update the UI, and left with instructions on how to do it.   I updated the existing ui file, saved it out, and ran the "Using Pyside-uic -o pythonfilename.py uifilename.ui" command.   No errors from the build, but %100 of the time i've tried using this method, it has failed.

I tried googling the answer for hours, and proposed the question to other people.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.   After pyside spits out the new python file (built from the UI file), theres a line of code at the beginning that will say something along the lines of "from PySide import QtCore, QtGui"

"PySide" has to be changed to "PyQt4".